# Unable to get form validity

Tags: angularjs

I'm unable to get form validity using $scope.myform.$valid & I get a undefined message "Cannot read property '$valid' of undefined".

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <form name="myform">
    Name: <input type="text" ng-model="user.name" /><br>
    Email: <input type="email" ng-model="user.email" /><br>
 </form>
</body> 

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  console.log($scope.myform.$valid);  
});
```

Plnkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/P2kg1l64d4t7k7X4d4jh?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because, when your controller is instanciated and this line of code is executed, the form has not been added to the scope yet.

Add this function to your controller instead:

```
$scope.click = function() {
    alert($scope.myform.$valid);
};
```

and add this to your form:

```
 <button type="button" ng-click="click()">is form valid?</button>
```

and you'll see that, when clicking the button, you'll be able to get the validity of the form.

Here's the updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/gfjfRfd1n0JL3ZVV1i46?p=preview).